Changing Variable in Action Listener Not Executing
I have recently started to learn java. My problem is that there is one line (or two) that does not execute (or something else).
Here is the script:
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class autoclicker extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    boolean autoclicking;

    JButton button;

    autoclicker() throws AWTException {
        button = new JButton();
        button.setBounds(200, 100, 100, 50);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(button);
        this.autoclicking = false;
        this.startRunning();
    }

    public void startRunning() throws AWTException
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (autoclicking == true)
            {
                mouseClick();
                wait(50);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void wait (int x)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(x);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void mouseClick() throws AWTException
    {
        try {
            Robot bot = new Robot();
            bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        }
        catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == button)
        {
            if (autoclicking == false)
            {
                autoclicking = true;
            }
            else if (autoclicking == true)
            {
                autoclicking = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

The culprit(s) are the lines autoclicking = true; and/or autoclicking = false; I have written lines such as System.out.println("test"); inside of the if (autoclicking == false) statement.
So in short, when I press the button, it successfully recognizes the source as the button, successfully recognizes that 'autoclickingis equal to false, but does not change autoclicking to true. I do know that it is true, as I tried writingSystem.out.println("test")` to test if it is true, but it never prints it.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.
I can't seem to find solutions to this, so I really didn't try anything. As you see, in this script there is no main void, because I tried running this script in a "main" class:
import java.awt.AWTException;

public class autostarter  {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws AWTException
    {
        new autoclicker();
    }
}


I would encourage you to take a look at Atomic Access and in particular focus on the volatile keyword.  One might also consider making use of something like AtomicBoolean

Not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Can you [edit] your question and explain what you want to achieve - rather than asking why your implementation does not work? I see several problems in your code - apart from not successfully changing the value of autoclicking - hence solving that problem will probably not  cause your program to do what you want it to do. Therefore, I suggest that you explain what you want the program to do.

You can try this statement within the else if (autoclicking == true) { .. } and see you are getting the desired result: mouseClick();. Also, comment the this.startRunning();.
